# Having trouble with jquery animate() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to use jQuery to animate every button on the page and then display the value of that button in a span tag. JShint shows no syntax errors but the code is not working, help would be appreciated.

jQuery code:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
            'background-color': '#142900',
            'width': '50px',
            'height': '30px'
        },
        1000,
        function() {
            $('.screen').val($(this).val());
        });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="calculator_area">
        <h1>Below you see a fully functional calculator. Ready to get get your hands dirty?!</h1>
        <span class="screen"></span>
        <div class="calculator">
            <button>1</button>
            <button>2</button>
            <button>3</button>
            <br>
            <button>4</button>
            <button>5</button>
            <button>6</button>
            <br>
            <button>7</button>
            <button>8</button>
            <button>9</button>
            <br>
            <button>0</button>
            <button>+</button>
            <button>-</button>
            <br>
            <button>x</button>
            <button>/</button>
            <button>=</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.screen').val($(this).val());`

Should be:

`$('.screen').text($(this).text());`

Since neither your `<span>` nor `<button>` elements have a `value` property.

Comment: @Smartboy Would you kindly accept the answer if it answers your question?